# why would a malloc/new return a pointer to the middle of a block?

Tags: memory, vector, heap-memory, corruption

General Background:

I am attempting to analyze a dump where a heap corruption occurs. The heap corruption takes place in std::vector.push_back - when the vector capacity is exceeded and more space is required, the call to the "free" of the old vector fails.

Analysis details:

From the analysis of the dump, I've seen that the pointer which is "freed" is in the middle of an existing "HEAP_ENTRY" block. I've seen this by enumerating all the blocks of the relevant heap using "!heap -h " and finding that the free'd block resides between two existing blocks (the difference between them is significant, certainly not only the 8-16 bytes of metadata, or something of this sort).

Questions:

1. Can a previous heap corruption cause the heap manager to return an address to the middle of a block, thus necessarily causing a crash when I attempt to free it ?
2. If 1. is true, that means that using pageheap isn't very useful here, because the corruption seems to take place on data which is always writable, so I don't think pageheap (gflags option) will be able to detect this. Do you have any suggestion how I might catch the point at which this kind of corruption occurs ?

Thanks a lot,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it to be a stale pointer, it sounds like it was probably validly allocated in the past - but presumably also freed in the past and then allocated over by a larger block.

In that scenario the problem is a double-free.  If your code is multi-threaded it could be a thread safety problem leading to stale pointers.

Comment: Can double free'ing lead to a situation where a later "malloc" returns a bad pointer, e.g: to the middle of a larger block ?

Comment: Potentially, but that's not my guess.  I'm guessing that you have: a = malloc(); free(a); b = malloc(); free(a);

Answer (score 1):

You might be best to use tools to track down better clues to what is going wrong.

- Valgrind is quite good.
- Some operating systems have built in malloc() diagnostics that can be enabled on the fly via environment variables with no additional effort.  Check the manual page for malloc() on your system.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but in case someone finds it useful, I did end up finding the problem via the "Full-page heap" option of gflags.exe (click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543097(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info about that).